# How does one find the reduced Singular Value Decomposition of a row or column vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If we treat a column vector $a$ as an $n \times 1$ matrix, or a row vector $a^T$ as a $1 \times n$ matrix, how would one write out the reduced singular value decomposition of $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a=(a/\| a \|) \begin{bmatrix} \| a \| \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

This pretty much follows by knowing the shape of a reduced SVD: if $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ then $U \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times r}, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}, V^* \in \mathbb{C}^{r \times n}$, where $r=\text{rank}(A)$. Now take $m=k,r=1,n=1$ (where $a$ is $k \times 1$).

Comment: The shape of the reduced SVD makes total sense, how do you find the values of $\Sigma$ and $V^T$ to be 1 though?

Comment: Well, $\Sigma$ has to have nonnegative entries and $V^T$ has to have orthonormal columns. The only way for $V^T$ to have orthonormal columns is for it to be $e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta$. Then the only way for the result of that to be real with nonnegative entries in $\Sigma$ is to have $\theta=0$ and $\Sigma=[1]$.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @JoshBlack Actually I made an error, I forgot to normalize $U$.

Comment: For the row vector scenario, we have $m = 1$, $r = 1$, and $n = k$ and then $U$ and $V^T$ switch in the given equality, correct? Specifically, $a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} ||a|| \end{bmatrix}(a/||a||)$?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not an answer, but it might be instructive to write out the full SVD:

For a row $a^T$, let $U =1$, $\Sigma =\begin{bmatrix} \|a\| & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$V = \begin{bmatrix} {1 \over \|a\|} a^T \\ v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_n^T \end{bmatrix}$,
where ${1 \over \|a\|} a^T, v_2, \cdots,\ v_n$ form an orthonormal basis.

For a column $a$, replace $U,\Sigma, V$ by $V^T, \Sigma^T, U^T$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks :) a question if I may, to define $V$, any vectors $v_2, \ldots, v_n$ that form an orthonormal basis are valid singular vectors? I would guess so since we get $a$ from any orthonormal basis, but just to be sure!

Comment: @JavierTG Any orthonormal basis will suffice as long as one element is the unit vector in the direction of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The truncated SVD of $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ would be 
$$
\mathbf{a}
=
\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V}^{T},
$$
where $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{a} / \|\mathbf{a}\|\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma} = [\|\mathbf{a}\|] \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{V} =[1] \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$.

Essentially, the only non-trivial thing in this decomposition is to normalize the length of $\mathbf{a}$ to obtain $\mathbf{U}$, because the decomposition (at least to the best of my knowledge) requires that $\mathbf{U}$ (and $\mathbf{V}$) have orthonormal columns.

The full SVD could be obtained by setting
$\mathbf{U} = \left[ \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{a}\|}\mathbf{a} \;\; \mathbf{U}^{\prime}\right]\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, with $\mathbf{U}^{\prime}$ being any $n \times (n-1)$ matrix with orthonormal columns that are also orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$,
 $\mathbf{\Sigma} = [\|\mathbf{a}\| \; 0\; 0 \; \dots \; 0]^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{V} =[1] \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$.